# Vertically Aligning link in Navigation Menus

Tags: html, css, navigation, vertical-alignment, navbar

I was just wondering how to align links in a navigation menu in the middle vertically, as I have tried vertical align and it is not working and have searched stack overflow and have found no answers.

**Note:** the navmenu usually goes the full length of the page and the link are at the top, not in the middle.
Here is the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QGm68/)

Here is the code:

CSS:

```
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.top {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 4px solid white;
}

.left {
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 4px solid white;
}

.menuandtop { bgcolor: yellow; }

.main {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: pink;
    border-radius: 10px;
    float: right;
}

a { text-decoration: none; }

.navmenu { list-style-type: none; }

.navmenu li a {
    color: #2E2E2E;
    font-family: arial;
    font-face: arial;
    font-weight: bold;
}

ul.navmenu a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navmenu li {
    background: rgb(255,50,50);
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,50,50,1) 0%, rgba(255,109,109,1) 50%, rgba(255,40,40,1) 52%, rgba(255,0,0,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(255,50,50,1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(255,109,109,1)), color-stop(52%, rgba(255,40,40,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255,0,0,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,50,50,1) 0%, rgba(255,109,109,1) 50%, rgba(255,40,40,1) 52%, rgba(255,0,0,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,50,50,1) 0%, rgba(255,109,109,1) 50%, rgba(255,40,40,1) 52%, rgba(255,0,0,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,50,50,1) 0%, rgba(255,109,109,1) 50%, rgba(255,40,40,1) 52%, rgba(255,0,0,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,50,50,1) 0%, rgba(255,109,109,1) 50%, rgba(255,40,40,1) 52%, rgba(255,0,0,1) 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff3232', endColorstr='#ff0000', GradientType=0 );
    filter: none;
    height: 20%;
    text-align: center;
}

.li1 { border-bottom: 1px solid #2E2E2E; }

.li2 { border-top: 1px solid #2E2E2E; }

.li3 {
    border-top: 1px solid #2E2E2E;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2E2E2E;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body height="1000px" bgcolor="#2E2E2E">
<div class="menuandtop">
  <div class="top"> </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="left">
    <ul class="navmenu">
      <li class="li1"><a href="index.html" class="a1">Home</a></li>
      <li class="li3"><a href="index.html" class="a1">Home</a></li>
      <li class="li3"><a href="index.html" class="a1">Home</a></li>
      <li class="li3"><a href="index.html" class="a1">Home</a></li>
      <li class="li2"><a href="index.html" class="a1">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer"> </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here you are:

http://jsfiddle.net/J7P2c/

just add the following code:

```
.left {
  display:table;
}

.navmenu{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Update: updated fiddle,

although on firefox it worked fine, on chrome there seemed to be some kind of error produced by the height of the li, so remove the following:

```
.navmenu li{
 height: 20%;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Vr8cv/1/

Comment: Did you check the fiddle?

Comment: he don't want to increase the li height. he want to move the entire block into vertically center of the left div.

Comment: hmm... just noticed that although it looks great on firefox, on chrome looks like what you said... let me look into it

Comment: when I make the li go the full length of the page, the links go back to the top, I have to click on the link, not the whole box and the bottom hlaf of the last link gets cut off. here is what I mean [link] (http://imgur.com/XeIqP5u). Plz help

Comment: please try to use the updated fiddle. the screenshot you showed is from the first fiddle...

Answer (score 1):

There are a few way this can be achieved, one way is to create an invisible inline-block element with 100% height which the navigation is vertically aligned to. Change your CSS in the following way:

```
.left{
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 4px solid white;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

Font size is set to 0 to remove white space.

```
.left:after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 0;
}
```

The :after pseudo-element is used to create the invisible element.

```
.navmenu{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The menu is then set to be inline-block and the font-size set to offset the zeroed font size in the parent element.

http://jsfiddle.net/D7V7p/